# Google Webmaster Geographic target: Increases or Decreases Traffic?

Tags: google, google-search-console, traffic, search-results

My website is an english video streaming website that gets visitors from all over the world (about 70,000 per day). 35% of my traffic is from the US.

Now, in google Webmaster, if I were to set my geographic target to USA, will I get more overall traffic or less than what I am getting right now?

*most of my traffic is organic from google*

Answer (score 2):

Here's a video from Matt Cutts explaining the geographical location
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ei_duGzEl94

From my own experience with my websites, I changed from default to Mexico and I didn't see that much boost in traffic.